# Return values PL/SQL Function

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-function

I try to create the PL/SQL function to get the different path with "select" statement record but can't to display any record. I'm not sure the function is correct. Please help to check it. Thanks for all.

The PL/SQL run in the oracle DB 12C

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE package_gov AS

 FUNCTION GOV_LOCATION_TXT (P_ORG_ID NUMBER, P_PO_HEADER_ID NUMBER) 
 RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  v_po_loc_txt VARCHAR2(200);

  BEGIN

    BEGIN

        SELECT CASE WHEN DEPT_LINE IS NOT NULL AND PRJ_NAME IS NULL
     THEN      


'GOV\'||TEAM_CODE||'\'||DEPT_LINE||'\'||CUST_NAME||'\'||PO_NUMBER||'\'


       WHEN DEPT_LINE IS NOT NULL AND PRJ_NAME IS NOT NULL
     THEN    'GOV\'||TEAM_CODE||'\'||DEPT_LINE||'\'||CUST_NAME||'\'||PRJ_NAME||'\'||PO_NUMBER||'\' 
          END   ABC_TEXT  

    INTO v_po_loc_txt 
    FROM               (SELECT DISTINCT po.SEGMENT1 PO_NUMBER,
                        po.ORG_ID,
                        sup.VENDOR_NAME       CUST_NAME,
                        po.ATTRIBUTE14       DEPT_LINE,
                        po.ATTRIBUTE15       TEAM_CODE, 
                        (SELECT pap.segment1 
                          FROM pa_projects_all pap
                          WHERE pda.project_id = pa.project_id
                          ) PRJ_NAME,

                           FROM  APPS.PO_HEADERS_ALL po,
                                 APPS.ap_suppliers sup,
                                 APPS.PO_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL pda
                             WHERE po.VENDOR_ID = sup.VENDOR_ID
                                   AND po.po_header_id = pda.po_header_id
                                   AND pda.project_id = p_id
                                   AND po.ORG_ID = P_ORG_ID 
                                   AND po.po_header_id = P_PO_HEADER_ID )                    
                               ;





END;
RETURN v_po_loc_txt;
END;

END package_gov;
```

For actual result as "GOV\BS\AC\ABC company ltd\12345678" or "GOV\BS\AC\ABC company ltd\P-12345\12345678"

The sql answer as follows: 
1.  GOV\BS\AC\ABC company ltd\12345678
2.  GOV\BS\AC\ABC company ltd\P-12345\12345678

Then, I try to write the testing script to call the function but cannot to display any record.

```
SELECT 'DEPT:\' || package_gov.GOV_LOCATION_TXT(po.org_id, 
        po.po_header_id) || 
       ' mdir ' ||
        'B:\' ||
   package_gov.GOV_LOCATION_TXT(po.org_id, po.po_header_id) 
FROM apps.po_headers_all po
  WHERE 1=1 
    and last_update_date > sysdate - 360
     and package_gov.GOV_LOCATION_TXT(h.org_id, h.po_header_id) is not null
   ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting all the issues in your function as following:

1. `P_ID` is declared and used directly in the query without initializing it. Means `P_ID` is null and which will restrict first query to result anything. Hence, `v_po_loc_txt` will be null. (I am considering that `pda.project_id` is PK and do not contain NULLs.
2. `IF (p_id != 'NULL') THEN`. `P_ID` is number and cannot be compared like this. You should use `IF P_ID IS NOT NULL THEN`
3. `N_ORG_ID` and `N_PO_HEADER_ID` is not even declared and initialized.
4. Also, You can not return 2 values using function. Function will always return the first value. I.e. `v_po_loc_txt` which will be always NULL as mentioned in point#1.

Please correct all the issues and then try again.

Mainly, the issue is non-initialized `P_ID`.

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi, All. I just update my script but the function cannot to display any record. Then, I try to run the sql and result is fine. Any suggestion for the function?